# How to convert scala.some to scala.mutable.Map?

Tags: json, scala, recursion, logging, data-masking

i am trying to write code to mask nested json fields..

```
 def maskRecursively(map :mutable.Map[String,Object]):mutable.Map[String,Object] ={
val maskColumns = PII_Data.getPIIData()
for((k,v) <- map){
  if(v.isInstanceOf[Map[String,Object]]){
    maskRecursively(map.get(k).asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[String,Object]])
  }else if(v.isInstanceOf[List[Object]]) {

  } else {
    if(maskColumns.contains(k)){map+=(k->"*****")}
  }

}


map }
```

calling this method from ..

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val result = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, classOf[ java.util.Map[String,Object] ])
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val myScalaMap = result.asScala
    maskRecursively(result.asScala)
```

i am getting error while trying to iterate a nested json object ..

> Cannot cast value of type 'scala.Some' to type 'scala.collection.mutable.Map'

how do i recurse a complex nested json object this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging , i was able to solve this..

```
    def maskJson(jsonStr: String): String = {
    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val result = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, classOf[Map[String, Object]])
    val maskedJson = maskRecursively(result)
    mapper.writeValueAsString(maskedJson)

  }


  def maskRecursively(map: Map[String, Object]): collection.mutable.Map[String, Object] = {
    val mutable = collection.mutable.Map[String, Object]()
    val maskColumns = PII_Data.getJsonPIIFields()
    for ((k, v) <- map) {
      if (v.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]]) {
        mutable += k -> maskRecursively(v.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]])
      } else if (v.isInstanceOf[List[Object]]) {
        val list = v.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Object]]].map(i => maskRecursively(i)).toList
        mutable += k -> list
      } else {
        if (maskColumns.contains(k)) {
          mutable += (k -> "*****")
        }
        else {
          mutable += k -> v
        }
      }
    }
    mutable
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was

```scala
if(v.isInstanceOf[Map[String,Object]]){
    maskRecursively(map.get(k).asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[String,Object]])
```

There are a few issues:

1. You check if `v` is an instance of `Map`, but then attempt to cast it to `mutable.Map`. They are technically different types (mutable vs immutable).
2. You check the type of `v`, but then apply the cast to `map.get(k)`, which is going to be a different value and type from `v`. A map's `get` method returns an Option, hence the error message.
3. Thanks to type erasure on the JVM, the runtime won't be able to tell the difference between e.g. a `Map[String, Object]` and a `Map[SomethingElse, Whatever]` - both will just look like `Map` at runtime. The compiler should have given you a warning about the `isInstanceOf` call for this reason.

If you do an `isInstanceOf / asInstanceOf` combo, make sure the operand is the same each time. You already have `v`, so you don't need to look it up a second time from the map. And make sure you use the same type on both instanceOf calls.

Fix this by changing it to

```scala
if(v.isInstanceOf[mutable.Map[_, _]]){
    maskRecursively(v.asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[String,Object]])
```

Comment: the problem is i tried to get mutable map by val result = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, classOf[ collection.mutable.Map[String,Object] ]) but some of the list & map inside this is still immutable and hence casting fails..now i cannot proceed with immutable map as i need to update some values. please help me

Comment: You'll just need to add cases to handle those different classes. Like how you have a case to handle `mutable.Map`, just add another case to handle an `immutable.Map` and so on for List.